# Cannot implicitly convert type to int[]

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a mastermind game where I having the user guess a number sequence between 4-10 instead of colours but for some reason my `GetRandomNumberCount` gets the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type to int[]

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
// This method gets the quantity of random numbers to use in the game. 
public static int GetRandomNumberCount(int difficulty)
{
    int[] randomNumber = 0;   

    if(difficulty == 1)
    {
       randomNumber= GenerateRandomNumber(0, 4);
    }
    else if(difficulty == 2)
    {
       randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(1, 6);
    }
    else if (difficulty == 3)
    {
       randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(1, 11);
    }

      return randomNumber;
}
// This method generates the random numbers for the array of numbers. 
public static int[] GenerateRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{   
    // this declares an integer array with 5 elements
    // and initializes all of them to their default value
    // which is zero
    int[] test2 = new int[5];

    Random randNum = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < test2.Length; i++)
    {
        test2[i] = randNum.Next(min, max);
    }
    return test2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetRandomNumberCount` method returns `int`, not `int[]` while 
`GenerateRandomNumber` returns an *array*: `int[]`; seems that you have to 
*get an item* from `GenerateRandomNumber`:

```
public static int GetRandomNumberCount(int difficulty) {
  if (difficulty == 1)
    return GenerateRandomNumber(0, 4)[0]; // just 1st item
  else if (difficulty == 2)
    return GenerateRandomNumber(1, 6)[0];
  else if (difficulty == 3)
    return GenerateRandomNumber(1, 11)[0]; 
  else
    return 0;
}
```

or if you want to return an array, you have to modify `GetRandomNumberCount`:

```
// note int[] - it's an array that is returned
public static int[] GetRandomNumberCount(int difficulty) {
  if (difficulty == 1)
    return GenerateRandomNumber(0, 4);
  else if (difficulty == 2)
    return GenerateRandomNumber(1, 6);
  else if (difficulty == 3)
    return GenerateRandomNumber(1, 11); 
  else
    return new int[5]; // 5 zero items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cahnge declaration of method `GetRandomNumberCount` to this.

```
public static int[] GetRandomNumberCount(int difficulty)
```

Currently you are returning `array of int` from method and `return type` of method is a single `int`. So change it to return `array` of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something very important. You've declared and array and you're trying to assign an to the array type so maybe try this randomNumber[0]=YOUR NUMBER